# Authoritative Windows Fle Creation Date

Tags: windows, file, timestamp

Looking for a method to verify the age of a file (both CREATION and LAST MODIFIED dates) on a Windows NTFS system, specifically something less susceptible to manipulation than the standard Windows file time/date stamps.

As far as I know, this is not possible unless one has a traceable backup history, but was hoping someone else might have a lead or idea? Or, if forensic investigation is required, what types of tools might be needed (or a referral to a forensic investigator in the SF Bay Area).

The use case in question is to be able to prove that a specific set of files on an old Windows 7 computer were created at the time designated by the "file creation" date of each file.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS has the USN journal that is used to track all changes to a volume.  As far as I know, it is typically disabled on Windows 7 - but you can always check.

Each changed is logged in a record containing the type of change and the object changed.

You can manage and query USN using "fsutil usn" tool

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788042.aspx